# d3.layout.treemap().children() in d3 version 5

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treemap

I am trying to update an older version of d3 to v5. 
Need to know how to convert the below code.

```
let treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
                           .children(function(d, de) { 
                               return de ? null : d['_children']; })
                           .sort(function(a, b) { 
                               return a['value'] - b['value']; })
                           .round(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the docs (https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#treemap) you can call it like this:

```
const treemap = d3.treemap()
    .tile(d3.treemapResquarify)
    .size([width, height])
    .round(true)
    .paddingInner(1);
```

I hope it helps